# Make closing as duplicate easier on mobile web

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, mobile-web

If I want to close a question as a duplicate on the desktop site I get a window like this:

[image]

Where the question can be scrolled, and the button "Vote To Close" is always visible.

So closing a question as a duplicate of a good canonical isn't any problem on a desktop. Whilst doing the same on mobile it goes horrible wrong:

[image]

(I couldn't make my scroll screenshot long enough to find the "Vote To Close" button before hitting the 2 MB image size limit.)

So my request:

**Can we have the same nested scroll on mobile-web?**

Comment: [Duplicate on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/171199/350567) (dating back to 2013)

Comment: I was wondering if nobody ever brought this up before....

Comment: The mobile interface has its own design and is in general -- IMO -- quite attractive, but it has more than a few weird bugs. I secretly think somebody is trying to scare people away from using it.

Comment: Well I wouldn't necessarilly call it a bug, but as it stands makes for very poor UX.

Comment: I love how perfect the enormous scroll screenshot is in describing what we mobile flaggers go through. I've looked at it from desktop too and it captures the mobile experience rather well.

Comment: @DavyM this is about 2/3 of the entire scroll. Uploading an 3M image isnt allowed unfortunately, and my scrollcapture got caught in a scrollable codefield.

Comment: @usr2564301 But what should we use then on mobile devices? The development of the SO/SE apps and the API (which the apps use to communicate with SE) is dead for some time now.

Comment: Make closing as duplicate easier o̶n̶ ̶m̶o̶b̶i̶l̶e̶ ̶w̶e̶b

Comment: @iBug Now, to close as duplicate on mobile. Oh wait...

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms NOOO MY PHONE SCREEN IS BURNING because there's too much friction and generated too much heat! What? You're asking where the friction comes from? I'm trying to close as duplicate and scrolling all the way down......

Comment: Since the dedicated mobile web interface no longer exists, should this be closed as no longer reproducible? (There's also the post [The "edit duplicates" dialog is broken on mobile](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/414946/1478931), which reports a different issue with the duplicate-list editor modal on mobile.)

Comment: @V2Blast I agree, I'll close it as no-repro.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should give the new responsive design for mobile a try. It fixes a lot of these annoying bugs that have been bothering us for a long time (while at the same time creating some, but overall it is better).

You can enable the responsive design by clicking `full site` in the page footer.

Then it looks like this:

> [image]

Comment: Welk that certainly fixes this. However the rest of the layout is plain horrible. Font sizes for example are wayyyyy of for usage on a mobile device.

Comment: Well, yes. They should fix that definitely. But at least you don't need to refresh to see your reputation updates, comments, etc.

Comment: The vote to close button & bottoms of tall vertically scrolled code blocks are still always out of my laptop window under the responsive design.