# Does upvoting a comment that flags a post as duplicate flag the post?

Tags: support, flags, duplicate-questions

When someone flags a question as duplicate, a comment is automatically created:

> Possible duplicate of [link].

If someone else flags the question as duplicate with the same link, it automatically casts an upvote to that comment.

Question is, does upvoting that comment automatically flag the post as duplicate without having to click on `flag` ? I could not find an answer [there](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates).

Comment: I don't think so but if there isn't such a feature then this should be an inspiration for one. Quick flagging and moderating tools will only help our community.

Comment: @window.document if two people flag as two different duplicates, then what happens if you upvote both?

Comment: Just to voice a contrary opinion: flagging (and for high-rep users the equivalent close voting) should never be as trivial as clicking an arrow icon on a post. As inconvenient as it is, one _should_ have to explicitly select a flag or close-vote reason. It's very easy to misclick, and anyway having a vote action imply hard moderation action would be contradictory to the basic mechanics of Stack Overflow.

Comment: @AndrasDeak moreover, it's not particularly hard to dupe vote right now. If somebody has already flagged as a dupe, you can see the automatically generated comment and if you want to subsequently vote as well, then any of the previous dupe votes are pre-populated with a count of the number of flags for that question. E.g., you can see that 2 people flagged/voted for **A** and 1 voted for **B** and those are the only choices you have unless you populate the filter. So it takes 3 clicks instead of 1 for subsequent dupe votes - hardly an insurmountable amount.

Comment: @VLAZ more or less, [except on mobile](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/376287/make-closing-as-duplicate-easier-on-mobile-web) ;)

Comment: @AndrasDeak I don't use mobile. How does it work there?

Comment: @VLAZ Check the link. On the (old, non-responsive) mobile view if you select a dupe target you have to scroll all the way down in an embedded version of the dupe target complete with 25 elaborate answers only to find the "vote to close" button at the very bottom. Questions that tend to be used as dupe targets usually have a lot of answers so this happens a lot. Unfortunately the new responsive mobile site is ugly and uncomfortable in _different_ ways.

Comment: @AndrasDeak ah, I see. So, in short: horribly.

Comment: @VLAZ well it's not the end of the world. It's just usually simpler to scroll all the way to the bottom of the page like a maniac, and then crawl back up on the question you're trying to close (which usually has fewer, shorter answers) and hit the button. And I'd rather keep this broken workflow than have comment votes trigger flagging or close votes. Especially since people will upvote anything.

Comment: @VLAZ right now nothing happens but if so then the amount of votes on any comment pointing out duplicates should be taken in considerations for judging the nature of the question.

Comment: @AndrasDeak I disagree, you can un-vote a comment one time. And a click as a moderation tool will serve a very good alternative for quick and effective moderation. This will only make stackoverflow a better place.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

No it doesn't.

As you point out flagging or voting to close the question as a duplicate of the same question does upvote the comment.

And if the question is eventually closed with that duplicate, the comment is automatically deleted.

Comment: It doesn't? I had no idea. I was always under the impression that it did.

Comment: Maybe it should?

Comment: @AbraCadaver At the very least, it should be made clear that upvoting _doesn't_ additionally flag/vote.  I think it should also be made clear that simply posting a comment in the format of "Possible duplicate of ... " doesn't actually do anything.  I see people do that _a lot_.  They see all of those comments auto-generated from flagging/VtC and just copy that format without understanding that those were auto-posted.

Comment: @PatrickQ :-(  I did that a couple of times when I was new.

Comment: @AbraCadaver I have done this too and I can explain my reasoning: With the prevalence of canned comments, and this looking (*being*) such, it wasn't at all clear this was a system behaviour. Being unfamiliar with the system yet, I didn't go for "flag" because I was still afraid of making a mistake. So, with low rep, it wasn't obvious that the comment is generated from flagging/close voting. Having enough rep, I can see something like "close (1)", so I know there is one close vote and I can see the comment. So, it's easier to make the link then.