# The "edit duplicates" dialog is broken on mobile

Tags: bug, status-review, mobile-web, design

When trying to add another linked duplicate, the opened popup is slightly misplaced:

[image: Screenshot of the UI]

As the "Add" button is on the left side of the popup and can't be reached through scrolling, the UI is not usable on mobile devices. This is both present in the "mobile" (the one I prefer to use) and "full (responsive)" version.

---

<sub>Screenshot produced in Firefox 83.1.0 on a [Nokia 5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nokia_5) (variant [TA-1053](https://nokiapoweruser.com/nokia-5-receiving-november-android-security-update-now/)).</sub>

Comment: Technically, Firefox Mobile [isn't supported](https://browsers.stackoverflow.design/), however, Stack Overflow only support the last 2 versions of a browser and you're running 83.1.0. You appear to be about 12 versions behind; I'm running 95.2 on Android.

Comment: Repro'd on the latest version of Chrome for Android (v96.0.4664.104). Looks like the dialog on `https://[SITE_URL]/questions/originals/[QUESTION_ID]/edit` is not responsive yet, compared to the flag/close dialog on normal case.

Comment: Doesn't just stop there. It's also broken on the mod message and CM message pages. That said, this didn't just happen - the dialogs have just not been made responsive, which is really disappointing and frustrating on pages that are otherwise responsive

Comment: @Zoe Hope you mods are raising cain over the lack of quality control on the recent UI rollouts. Afraid to call them *upgrades* due to a lot of functionality that  has actually been degraded. It's like UX was completely ignored

Comment: @zoe but it was at least usable the last time I've tried ... Something must have changed (at least on "mobile") ...

Comment: @JonasWilms Maybe you confused it for the regular close dialog? Closing as a dupe isn't terribly broken anymore, but editing dupes was, as far as I know, never fixed. (Obligatory disclaimer that I may have missed it working, and may be wrong. I don't spend a lot of time hammering dupes on my phone anymore, much less editing lists)

Comment: @zoe no, I would've noticed much earlier if the dupe close itself was broken :). For a long time I've visited SO only via phone, and I do regularily edit the duplicate list, so _some time ago_ this worked. Since about two years I use my phone less frequent, so could be that this is broken for a longer time ...

Comment: You're probably right then; I've substantially decreased my phone use for dupes, so it's not implausible that it was both fixed and re-broken since last time I checked. I still hope they fix all the popups soon (and the various other things; it's really frustrating to work with ~20% of the UI being broken, dysfunctional, or just flat out annoying)

Comment: Agreed. Also I hope they do not shut down the good ol' "mobile" UI anytime soon. The "full" site is just way too much whitespace on small screens (in the "mobile" UI I can see 5 questions in the question list, and just 2 in the "full" version).

Comment: *"Also I hope they do not shut down the good ol' "mobile" UI anytime soon."* meant to be end of the year, or shortly afterwards, last I heard.

Comment: Also repro on Firefox Mobile on IOS. The same problem also affects edit reviews (i.e. if you see "edit(1)" below a post, indicating a pending edit sugestion, and tap it, you can't access some parts of the Javascript pseudo-dialog).

Comment: As an _almost_ acceptable workaround, you can't paste a link into the dialog, but you can type the numeric ID of the target there. For example, to link to https://stackoverflow.com/q/12345678, memorize and type 12345678 into the search box (even though you can't see what you are typing) and Return.

Comment: You *can* actually paste a link, if you insert enough spaces at the beginning to get the cursor to be visible. Then, your phone's paste UI should also be visible. The spaces don't cause any issues. @tripleee

Comment: Whoa, thanks for the tip. /-:

Comment: Not to be confused with the mobile *app*, which [is on its last legs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/383026/mobile-app-infrastructure-being-decommissioned).

Comment: As reported in https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/424609/adding-duplicates-on-a-small-screen-mobile-is-impossible-again the spacing hack no longer works.

Answer (score 2):

While a fix for this extremely annoying issue is still in the works (since last year?), here's a palliative solution that makes my dupe-list editing experience on mobile slightly less vexatious:

(I'm on an iPhone)

- Turn off the screen orientation lock on your device
- Rotate the phone 90 deg to have horizontal orientation.

This way when tapping the input bar, the cursor is within the viewport and the "Paste" context popup is also within reach.
Same goes for the "Add" button at the bottom of the dialog.

This is *far* from ideal since it forces me to change the screen orientation lock, which I usually keep locked on vertical, but it sort of works on small screens.

Comment: What browser? [Safari](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safari_%28web_browser%29)? Firefox?

Comment: I’m using Safari

Comment: This workaround does not provide any relief for me, in Firefox on an iPhone 12 Mini.