# Adding duplicates on a small-screen mobile is impossible again

Tags: bug, duplicate-questions, user-experience, mobile-web

I am again unable to edit the list of duplicates from my phone.

In brief, when a question is closed as a duplicate, gold-badge owners in one of the question's tags are able to edit the list of duplicates (this comes with the "Mjølnir" privilege, where you are given a "golden hammer" so you can single-handedly close as duplicates, and reopen closed duplicate in a tag where you have earned a gold badge).

[image: Question with duplicates, where you can click Edit]
[image: The resulting view of duplicates, with Add and Remove buttons]

However, the JavaScript pseudo-dialog you get when you click the <kbd>Add</kbd> button is too large, so you can't access its <kbd>OK</kbd> button (or conveniently paste a duplicate link - but you can insert some 40 spaces and then you're able to paste a link).

[image: The dialog to add a duplicate, with no close box or Okay button]

[image: Inserting spaces to be able to add a link]

(The problem is somewhat exacerbated by iOS, which zooms the text box when you try to enter data into it.)

You can scroll the screen sideways a little bit, enough to *almost* expose the <kbd>OK</kbd> button, but not quite enough (and then of course, even if you could expose it, you can't really click it while you are dragging it into view; as soon as you let go, the phone snaps its focus back to the middle of the screen).

Previously, you were able to hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> after pasting a link and it would click the <kbd>OK</kbd> button which is out of reach, but this no longer works, since I think around a week back.

Images are from Firefox on an iPhone 12 Mini (iOS 16.4.1 (a)).

[Make closing as duplicate easier on mobile web](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/376287/make-closing-as-duplicate-easier-on-mobile-web) reports similar hardships, but the answer there was never a complete success, and it doesn't solve the problem I'm reporting.

Comment: Hat tip to Cody for the advice to type a lot of spaces so that I could paste. It worked for a while, though it was always a hassle.

Comment: Devils advocate time: I kind of wonder if this is going to be seen as a bug from "the other side". I don't get the feeling that you are really intended to be doing curation tasks on a screen that is too small using fingers that are too big. When things are a great pain to do, you should kind of take the hint you know instead of applying every workaround you can find. Clever though they might be.

Comment: I am able to comfortably use all other features of the site. This one is just not well designed.

Comment: Duplicate? [The "edit duplicates" dialog is broken on mobile](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/414946/the-edit-duplicates-dialog-is-broken-on-mobile)